# Float Overflow Error en while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

El objetivo de mi codigo es calcular F(xi) hasta que su valor sea >= a 0.9995, mientras sea menor, se seguira generando la iteracion del while y del for.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math
import pandas as pd

lambda_ = int(input("Ingresa el valor de lambda_: "))
e = 2.718281828459
search = {"f(xi)": [], "F(xi)": []}


count = 0
up = 0.9995
F_xi = 0
while up >= F_xi:
    if count == 0:
        operation = ((pow(e, -(lambda_)) * pow(lambda_, count)) /
                     math.factorial(count))
        search["f(xi)"].append(round(operation, 7))
        search["F(xi)"].append(round(operation, 7))
    else:
        operation = ((pow(e, -(lambda_)) * pow(lambda_, count)) /
                     math.factorial(count))
        search["f(xi)"].append(round(operation, 7))
        new_F = search["f(xi)"][count] + search["F(xi)"][-1]
        search["F(xi)"].append(round(new_F, 7))
        F_xi = search["F(xi)"][-1]
    count += 1


result = pd.DataFrame(search)
print(result)
```

Me da el error: OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

```
El error esta en:
operation = ((pow(e, -lambda) * pow(lambda, + (count))) /
                     math.factorial(count))
```

Si el valor de lambda fuese 5, el resultado de la tabla deberia de ser el siguiente:

```
       f(xi)       F(xi)
0     0.00673     0.00673
1     0.03368     0.04041
2     0.08422     0.12463
3     0.14037     0.26500
4     0.17546     0.44046
.
.
.
.                >= 0.9995
```

[image: Error de codigo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ojo que los factoriales crecen muy rapido, el último valor que puede soportar un factorial casteado a float es:

```
float(math.factorial(170))
```

Si haces:

```
float(math.factorial(171))
```

Te tirará el error en cuestión.

Como estas usando el factorial de divisor se castea implicitamente a `float`, lanzando el error.

Por lo que veo dos soluciones distintas, o intentas reducir el valor de `count` o puedes utilizar el tipo [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) para manejar numeros de esta magnitud a costa de rendimiento y rapidez.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math
import pandas as pd

lambda_ = int(input("Ingresa el valor de lambda_: "))
e = 2.718281828459
search = {"f(xi)": [], "F(xi)": []}


count = 0
up = 0.9995
F_xi = 0
while up >= F_xi:
    if count == 0:
        operation = Decimal(((pow(e, -lambda_) * pow(lambda_, -(count)))) /
                     math.factorial(count))
        search["f(xi)"].append(operation)
        search["F(xi)"].append(operation)
    else:

        for i in range(0,count):
            operation = Decimal(((pow(e, -lambda_) * pow(lambda_, -(count)))) /
                     math.factorial(count))
            search["f(xi)"].append(operation)
            new_F = search["f(xi)"][i] + search["F(xi)"][i-1]
            search["F(xi)"].append(new_F)
            F_xi = search["F(xi)"][-1]
    count += 1


result = pd.DataFrame(search)
print(result)
```

Solución inspirada en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174399/overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-float-in-python).

Comment: count digamos que es el valor de x, el cual sera utilizado para elevar "e"  a la "x" osea pow(e,x) y tambien count sera utilizado como "x" para dividir la toda la operacion entre el factorial de "x", que este caso "x" es count. Y aun asi modificandolo con "Decimal" me sigue dando error :(

Comment: @axel incluye el stacktrace completo del error por favor, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Añadi la imagen al codigo al ultimo, sin embargo el "count" nunca crecera a más de 100, porque los problemas que tengo que hacer el maximo numero de iteraciones es de 100, asi que el factorial no puede ser mayor a eso. Y le quite el for al codigo porque sino estaria imprimiendo de 0 a el largo de count cada vez que "count" crezca

Comment: Tiene que estar algo mal en el código porque el factorial se sigue casteando a float implícitamente por la división en la línea que se gatilla el error. El stacktrace que compartiste no muestra el número de línea y no tengo tu código actual como para ayudarte más, solo fijate que el dividendo sea UN decimsl y que el divisor sea un integer, como el que retorna el factorial.

Comment: Tenias razon, muchas gracias, una vez que use Decimal no borre un dato y eso me siguio dando el error. Gracias!!